# Regression analysis with separateing group in R

Tags: r, regression, lm

In my dataset, there are two group variables `shop and art`
here data example

```
read.csv(reg.csv)
structure(list(shop = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "c"), class = "factor"), art = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("b", "d"), class = "factor"), 
    Y = c(177L, 122L, 175L, 140L, 201L, 202L, 279L, 253L, 236L, 
    137L, 166L, 241L, 195L, 221L, 238L, 203L, 254L, 219L, 101L, 
    157L, 188L, 219L, 267L, 126L, 291L, 239L, 230L), x1 = c(1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x2 = c(0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), x4 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), x5 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), x6 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x7 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), x8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x9 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("shop", "art", "Y", "x1", "x2", 
"x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))
```

I need perform regression analysis for all groups separately.
The formula is simple

```
mymodel=lm(y~.,data=reg)
```

I.e. i must perform analysis for `a+b` group and `c+d` group separately.
In this example  we have only 2 groups(a+b and c+d)
where a,c-mean name of shop, and b,d -mean name of vendor code.

How can i perform regression ananysis separately by groups, cause in real data, there are several ten groups, manually divide on the datasets it's impossible.

Comment: [split, apply, combine](http://stat545.com/block024_group-nest-split-map.html).

Comment: @missuse, can you show me, how use this operators on my data?

Comment: I could, but encourage you to read the linked tutorial and come back if something is not clear.

Comment: @missuse I'm tried to use  split, and got a lot of errors. I would not like to fill a stackoverflow by number of posts related to errors, and  my task is one-time

Comment: @missuse, yes, even before writing this post. Before I write posts, I always search similar topics on the Internet, and if something does not work, I write a question. R is not my profile tool, but I rarely use it

Comment: It will work when you are following the guidelines of the tutorial. If your problem in reality is about combining the columns `shop` and `art` in the way you want, you can for example do so by typing `reg %>%
  unite("shopart", c("shop", "art"))  -> reg2`. This uses the `tidyr` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively common analytical pattern called split - apply - combine and it is fairly easy to perform with R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
```

create a function for lm:

```
my_lm <- function(df) {
  lm(Y ~ ., data = df)
}
```

run the models on nested groups of data:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(art, shop) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, my_lm),
         tidy = map(fit, tidy)) %>%
  select(-fit, - data) %>%
  unnest()
```

First you group by the variables by the desired variables, fit the lm model to the groups use tidy to extract the coefficients, remove unwanted columns and then unnest. The result is:

```
#output
  art    shop   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <fctr> <fctr> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 b      a      (Intercept)    31.0      269      0.115   0.927 
 2 b      a      x1            109        153      0.714   0.605 
 3 b      a      x2           - 23.0      223     -0.103   0.934 
 4 b      a      x3           - 15.0      185     -0.0810  0.949 
 5 b      a      x4             31.0      333      0.0931  0.941 
 6 b      a      x5             81.0      457      0.177   0.888 
 7 b      a      x6             77.0      162      0.475   0.718 
 8 b      a      x7           - 17.0      310     -0.0548  0.965 
 9 b      a      x8           - 15.0      214     -0.0700  0.956 
10 b      a      x9             54.0      349      0.155   0.902 
11 d      c      (Intercept)   199         98.8    2.01    0.0907
12 d      c      x1           - 15.7       60.8   -0.259   0.804 
13 d      c      x2              5.98      48.8    0.123   0.906 
14 d      c      x3              7.34      57.8    0.127   0.903 
15 d      c      x4           - 20.1       53.8   -0.373   0.722 
16 d      c      x5           - 43.2       41.8   -1.03    0.342 
17 d      c      x6              1.93      34.5    0.0560  0.957 
18 d      c      x7             31.9       40.5    0.787   0.461 
19 d      c      x8             36.0       45.9    0.786   0.462 
20 d      c      x9             10.7       49.7    0.215   0.837
```

There are many tutorials using the same or similar approach like the one I posted in my comment.